# Prove that $n^2 + n +1$ is not divisible by $5$ for any $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Prove that $n^2 + n +1$ is not divisible by $5$ for any $n$.

I believe this might be tried using division algorithm, or modular arithmetic. I don't see exactly how to start this... Please help.

Comment: $5\nmid (1^2+1+1)$

Comment: Your assertion is not true for $1 \le n \le 10$

Comment: I am extremely sorry, the question is to prove that it is NOT divisible

Comment: @Saurubh Please take the time to formulate the question clearly before you post it here. You expect others to invest time in it, so you should too. I've edited the question with "for any $n$" since that seems to be what you meant, but please don't make us guess.

Comment: @TMM I am very sorry, and even more so, as i have seen that i got so many responses from many people, will take great care next time.

Comment: My two cents: $n^2+n+1\equiv n^2-4n+1=n(n-4)+1=(n-1)(n-3)-2=(n-2)^2-3\pmod{5}$

Answer (score 12):

$5\nmid (n^2+n+1)$ for all integer $n$. Because
$$n^2+n+1 \equiv (n+3)^2 + 2 \pmod 5$$
So if $5\mid (n^2+n+1)$ for some $n$, then $n$ satisfies $(n+3)^2 \equiv 3 \pmod 5$. But $3$ is not quadratic residue modulo $5$. (You can check that $3$ is not quadratic residue easily.)

Answer (score 8):

If you don't know modular arithmetic you can also show it by induction. This is similar to the solution by rschwieb:

1. Prove that if $n^2 + n + 1$ is not divisible by $5$, then also $(n+5)^2 + (n+5) + 1$ is not divisible by $5$.
2. Prove explicitly the base cases: $n = 1, n=2, n=3, n=4, n=5$.
3. By induction this then holds for all $n$.

Comment: do you mean to say that i should put  n=5k, 5k+1, 5k+2, 5k+3, 5k+4 in $n^2 + n + 1$, and say that this is not divisible by 5, as there will be some constant which is not a multiple of 5.

Comment: No, this is simply induction which skips 5. You have to assume (this is the induction assumption) that $n^2 + n + 1$ is not divisible by $5$ for some $n$, and then based on that, prove (this is the induction step) that replacing $n$ with $n+5$ still gives you something not divisible by $5$. Since this induction skips 5 integers in each step, you have to prove the 5 base cases, to cover all possible (positive) integers.

Comment: well, i only know that induction is when you're proving for 1, assuming for n, and using that to prove for n+1. Since that does not apply here, I couldnt understand your solution, so can we use anything but induction, or rather, is my method acceptable?

Comment: Oh, now I understood your comment. You're saying plug $n=5k+r$ (for $0 \le r \le 4$) and do 5 proofs by induction. Yeah, that'll work. Anyway, this whole solution is not very elegant. It's better to learn modular arithmetic and then understand that proving for $n=0,1,2,3,4$ is enough, like rschwieb suggested.

Comment: so get a remainder, which will be there on the residue side of the mod, and get the contradiction for the initial assumption that given expression IS divisible?

Comment: @YoniRozenshein: the modular arithmetic and proof by induction are the exact same proof.  "Knowing modular arithmetic" just means you've already proven the induction.  Nothing more/less elegant here.

Comment: induction is overkill here, just plug $n=5k+r$, expand the square, collect multiples of $5$, voila. don't believe that modular arithmetic and induction are interchangeable techniques. modular arithmetic is algebra and induction is logic.

Comment: @suissidle, exactly my point, but I didnt understand your solution. can you see the first comment, in which i do as you say, and tell me if this is acceptable, as i think i havent used induction in there..

Comment: yes, your first comment is correct. in each case you'll get an expression like $5(\cdots)+s$ (where $s$ is some number), which is divisible by $5$ if and only if $s$ is divisible by $5$. you'll notice $s$ is never divisible by $5$; it always has a remainder in $\{1,2,3\}$. the $k$ is contained in the $(\cdots)$ so you can ignore it at this point; you can prove the general statement in one step without recourse to induction.

Comment: exactly, my only hesitation there is whether any natural number can be expressed as a function = $k$, 5n.

Answer (score 3):

it's enough to check it for $n\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$:
\begin{array}{c}
  n^2+n+1
    & \equiv
    & \begin{Bmatrix}
      0 + 0 + 1\\
      1 + 1 + 1\\
      4 + 2 + 1\\
      4 + 3 + 1\\
      1 + 4 + 1
      \end{Bmatrix}
    & (\operatorname{mod}5)
  \\
    & \equiv
    & \begin{Bmatrix}
      1\\
      3\\
      2\\
      3\\
      1
      \end{Bmatrix}
    & (\operatorname{mod}5)
\end{array}
where each 'vector' entry corresponds to a choice of $n$ (i know it's sloppy but tex gives me a headache)

Comment: i am sorry, but as a high school student, i have yet to study matrices

Comment: they're not matrices..i'm just summarizing the $5$ cases: you first check the congruence with the first value ($0+0+1$), then $1+1+1$, and so on

Answer (score 2):

It is not true :$1^2+1+1=3$ but $5$ does not divide $3$

Comment: This answer is no longer relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2):

actually it is **never** divisible by 5. To prove it, consider the possible class where $n$ belongs to, mod 5

Answer (score 2):

In fact $n^2+n+1$ is *never* divisible by $5$ for *any* $n$.

If it were, then the equation $n^2+n+1=0$ would hold mod 5, and you can verify by brute force it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is les elegant but seems more easier to come up with to me.

If $5|n^2+n-1 \rightarrow n^2+n=-1 \mod 5\rightarrow (n+1)(n)=1\mod 5$

So all you have to check is 5 tiny multiplications. (three if you don't do the one with zeroes.)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $5$ divides $n^2+n+1$.  Then $5$ also divides $(n-2)^2+2 = n^2+n+1-5(n-1)$. For every $n$, we know that $(n-2)^2$ must have its last digit equal to one of $1,4,5,6,9$ (this is true of the squares of all integers).  But then the last digit of $(n-2)^2 +2$ must be among $1,3,6,7,8$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

$\rm mod\ 5\!:\ 0\equiv (1\!-\!n)(1\!+\!n\!+\!n^2)\equiv \color{#C00}1\!-\!\color{#0A0}{n^3}\Rightarrow \color{#C00}n\equiv \color{#0A0}{n^4}\!\equiv 1\ or\,\ 0\:$ by Fermat. But $1,0$ are not roots.